# Custom Taxonomies data in Wordpress template files?

Tags: wordpress

If I make two custom posts how can I access Custom Taxonomy data in my custom Wordpress template files?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit difficult to understand, but read this:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Custom_Taxonomies

If you have any questions after that, post them here.

Answer (score 0):

This function is probably the one that will help you most:

[Function Reference/the_terms()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_terms)